# How to change an img src on a parent div hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, src

I'm having a problem with an image not changing on div hover using jQuery. Everything else changes accordingly except the image. Currently, the blue image stays the same and doesn't change. I also notice that the green image shows out of place when hovered which is weird. What am I doing wrong?

I created a jsfiddle problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/8bcfnd6f/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="widget">
    <div id="text-button-widget">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
        <img id="widget-img" src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/di8/KRL/di8KRL8ie.png"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#widget:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #0098db;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#widget').hover(function(){ // hover in
    $('#widget h2, #widget p').css('color','#fff');
    $('#widget-img').css('background', 'url("http://www.clipartkid.com/images/17/youtube-play-icon-clipart-Ns7Pf4-clipart.gif") no-repeat center center fixed');
}, function(){ // hover out
    $('#text-button-widget h2').css('color','#000');
    $('#text-button-widget p').css('color','#000');
    $('#widget-img').css('background', 'url("http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/di8/KRL/di8KRL8ie.png") no-repeat center center fixed');
});
```

Comment: i think the issue is you have an image element with an image, and you're changing the background, so the image element will still persist.

Comment: You can do this easily with no JS. https://jsfiddle.net/8bcfnd6f/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you code doesn't change the src, it just change BACKGROUND and add it to present src.
If You just need to change src, you should use code like this:

```
    $('#widget').hover(function(){ // hover in
    $('#widget h2, #widget p').css('color','#fff');
    $('#widget-img').attr("src", "http://www.clipartkid.com/images/17/youtube-play-icon-clipart-Ns7Pf4-clipart.gif");
}, function(){ // hover out
    $('#text-button-widget h2').css('color','#000');
    $('#text-button-widget p').css('color','#000');
    $('#widget-img').attr("src", "http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/di8/KRL/di8KRL8ie.png");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#widget-img').attr('src', 'http://www.clipartkid.com/images/17/youtube-play-icon-clipart-Ns7Pf4-clipart.gif')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you completely want to change the `<img>` you should set it's width and height to 0, and add padding accordingly. Then add the background image.

The CSS solution, as per your case. No Javascript needed.

```
#widget:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #0098db;
  color: #fff;
}
#widget:hover img {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: url("http://www.clipartkid.com/images/17/youtube-play-icon-clipart-Ns7Pf4-clipart.gif") no-repeat;
  background-size: 256px 256px;
  background-position: center center;
  padding: 128px;
}
```